# Add text in in front of millions of lines with Linux?

Tags: text, sed, large-data, large-files

I want to add important@ to 159 millions of lines.

I learned it's possible with `sed` on Linux.

Guide me if possible.

I know its possible to add at the end with:

```
sed 's/$/ | EXAMPLE/' file
```

Comment: Do you want to prepend it to each line of a file or several files? Or just some lines - how would you tell them from the lines that should stay unchanged?

Comment: @choroba each line, all lines.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to `$` which matches at the end of a line, `^` matches at the beginning.

```
sed -i~ 's/^/prefix:/' file1 file2...
```

The `-i~` changes the files "in place", leaving a backup with the `~` extension. If your sed doesn't support it, try plain `-i` (change in place without a backup).